# How to create interest in interest category?

Tags: mailchimp

As per below link create interest functionality is nto avaialable.
http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/interest-categories/interests/# 
But using API playgroung you can create interest. Even tried with REST api and I am able to create interest. Please let me know if "create interest " API has been removed from above page.

Answer (score 2):

I think it never wasn't on that page. This new API Documentation lacks many things that are possible.

If you want to create new interest you can just POST to this endpoint:
`/lists/{list_id}/interest-categories/{interest_category_id}/interests`

Example request body:

```
{
    "list_id": "id_of_the_list",
    "name": "name of the interest",
    "display_order": 1
}
```

So the answer for your question is that I am pretty sure they just haven't created documentation for that one yet.

Comment: Thank you. I confirm this works and at the same time this isn't documented. Just small correction - `list_id` is not needed in the POST payload, cos it is in the URL.